# How to use Dictionaries in Android like NSMutableDictionary in ios?

Tags: java, android, dictionary

I am very new to Android development. I am converting my iPhone app to Android. In my iphone application, I used `NSMutableDictionary` to store StudentName(Key) and StudentId(Value) from `NSXmlParser`. Because, each student have different id, each id have different details for the student. If the user search the StudentName using `UISearchBar`, I want to show the StudentName and also to retrieve the correct Id for that student. I want to do the same in Android app. I searched my level best in Google for this but, I can't find the exact solution for my problem. Can anyone please help to find out the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you *probably* want a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)... that's certainly a mutable key/value dictionary. It's not clear what you're doing with `NSMutableDictionary`, but if it's simple key/value lookup, then some implementation of `Map` (whether it's `HashMap` or something else) is appropriate.

You might want to read the [Java Collections tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html), too.

Comment: Mr.Jon Skeet thanks for your spot response. I was used NSMutableDictionry like this [mutableDictionaryObj setValue:@"100" forKey:@"StudentName"];. I will read Java Collections Tutorial before working in Android. Thanks. One more help can i get the details about HashMap in that tutorial. Thanks.

Comment: I think in general you need to find references between iOS collections and Java collections to  avoid similar questions in future.

Comment: @Gopinath: Well, you can read about maps in general there - `HashMap` is just one implementation. To be honest, if you're really new to Java I would try learning Java and its core framework classes *separately* from Android, writing small console apps to experiment. That's likely to be easier than experimenting via Android apps.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for your help. Really am very new to Android. Just now i started to read about Android and Java frameworks and other controls. Thanks for your help.